# Importing ES2015 module in Safari DP requires file extension

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

I'm currently testing ES2015 coverage on Safari Developer Preview (which claims to support 100% ES2015, modules included).

I've made a simple test, using the same syntax I've been using regularly when developing using ES2015 code (along with Babel.JS for transpiling and Browserify for bundling).

Unexpectedly my code wouldn't work without including the `.js` extension in the import statement. Is that standard behavior? I thought you could omit that.

```js
/* filename: scripts/alert.js */
export default class Alert {
    constructor(message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    
    show() {
        alert(this.message);
    }
}

// Another file


/* filename: scripts/index.js */
import Alert from "./alert.js"; // this won't work if I change it to 'import Alert from "./alert";'

(new Alert("Hello, World!")).show();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ES2015 Modules</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ES2015 Modules</h1>
    <script async="async" type="module" src"scripts/index.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The *ModuleSpecifier* is used by the environment to load a module. It's not something the language stipulates, so the environment may or may not require the `.js` extension.

Comment: I didn't know that. I guess I'll have to always put the `.js` extension just to be sure, as a good practice during development (even with transpilation and bundling)

Answer (score 2):

> Unexpectedly my code wouldn't work without including the .js extension in the import statement. Is that standard behavior? I thought you could omit that.

It's not the browser's job to second-guess what that resource specifier means to the server. You can certainly configure your server to respond to the GET without the `.js` by delivering a matching file that has `.js`, but that's server configuration.

There's likely to be evolution in this regard. For instance, right now [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#resolve-a-module-specifier) requires that a module resource specifier start with either `/` or `./`. This is specifically so that...

> ...in the future we can allow custom module loaders to give special meaning to "bare" import specifiers, like `import "jquery"` or `import "web/crypto"`. For now any such imports will fail, instead of being treated as relative URLs.

Comment: I really thought when you import a module the browser would try to load it with the `.js` extension in the get request. My code editor autocomplete suggests imports without the `.js` extension.
I really shouldn't omit that part, then

Comment: @Zorgatone: It took forever for this to get even as nailed-down as it is. :-) I think we're starting with "keep it simple" and then evolving from there.

Comment: I know: really! That's why I was a bit surprised, and excited to try it out